# add plotting symbol in CCA plot in R

Tags: r, plot, vegan

I want to generate canonical correspondence analysis(CCA) plot, to show the influence of environmental parameters on species distribution using this code:

```
spe <- read.csv("spe.csv", row.names=1, sep=";")
env <- read.csv("env.csv", row.names=1, sep=";")
ccamodel <- cca(spe~., env)
plot(ccamodel, xlim=c(-1.5,2), ylim=c(-1,1.5), display=c("sp","cn"))
```

[Here is the output generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKudW.png) where the environmental variables and species name are highlighted in blue and red respectively.
My questions:  How I can put the same symbol as a filled circle or a filled square before or after each species name in the plot?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the manual page for plotting `cca` results (`?plot.cca`). The examples show how to plot symbols.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  but as you can see I am not using `plot.cca`, but I'm using `plot`. Then your suggestion  does not help. and when I  use ?plot, i don't see the  what to do exactly.

Comment: You do not understand R. When you give the output from `cca()` to `plot()`, it sends it to `plot.cca` so you are using it even if you don't realize it. The `plot()` function is generic. It changes its behavior depending on what you give it. If you want to see what to do exactly, you need to provide reproducible data so we can show you. I have no access to "spec.csv" or "env.csv". Use `dput(spe)` and `dput(env)` and paste the results into your question. If it is a lot of data just give us a subset.

Comment: Thanks, you are right I am a beginner in R and I start learning the basic. Here  are the two csv file I am using : http://www.mediafire.com/file/r54e4ymw5wz1t0a/cca.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot quite match your plot. The scaling of the biplot is different but otherwise this accomplishes what you want.

```
out <- plot(ccamodel, type="n", xlim=c(-2.5, 2.75), ylim=c(-1, 1.5))
text(ccamodel, dis="bp", scaling="species", col="blue", cex=.8)
points(ccamodel, pch=16, scaling="species", display="sp", col="red")
text(ccamodel, dis="species", scaling="species", col="red", cex=.8, pos=4)
```

The text is shifted to the right of the points for clarity. The `pos=` argument sets the position. If you leave it out the text is centered on top of the point, values of 1 - 4 put it below, left, over, and right of the point.

[image: CCA Plot]

Comment: You change my life:) This is what I was looking for.  thanks a lot!